# How can I calculate time correctly?

Tags: python, line, python-mode

*Here is my code *
I want get ühole number

```
from time import time
import math
start=time()
total_time= 30
while time!=0:
    move=input('Chess move:')
    if move !='off':
     print(start)
     remaining_time=math.floor(total_time-start)
     print('Remaninig time:',remaining_time)
    else:
        end=time()
        break
```

*Here is result*

```
Chess move:
>>> f2-f4
1667907784.8287
Remaninig time: -1667907755
Chess move:
>>> off
```

But I want result like this:

[image]

Comment: `math.floor(total_time-start)` comes down to `30 - 1667908283`. Makes sense that you get an negative number right?

Comment: `time` is a function; it will never equal 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

time.time() returns seconds since Jan 1 1970.
So 30-1667908542 is a negative number.
What you want to do is calculate the elapsed time and subtracting that from your time limit.

```
from time import time
import math
start=time()
max_time= 30
remaining_time = max_time
while remaining_time>0:
    move=input('Chess move:')
    if move !='off':
        print(start)
        time_elapsed=math.floor(time()-start)
        remaining_time=max_time-time_elapsed
        print('Remaninig time:',remaining_time)
```

When the loop exits the time is over.

Answer (score 0):

Python `time.time()` returns time since January 1, 1970. Not since start of the program

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#epoch

It is better to compare difference between current time and start_time

```
from time import time
import math
start=time()
total_time= 30
while time!=0:
    move=input('Chess move:')
    if move !='off':
     print(start)
     remaining_time=math.floor(time()-start)
     print('Remaninig time:',remaining_time)
    else:
        end=time()
        break
```